# Transformation of random variables and second order stochastic dominance

Tags: statistics, decision-theory, risk

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables where $X$ has SOSD (second order stochastic dominance) over $Y$. Let $g(\cdot)$ be a monotonic function and $X'  = g(X)$ and $Y' = g(Y)$.

Under what conditions of $g(\cdot)$ $X'$ has SOSD over $Y'$? I know that if $g$ is linear, SOSD property is reserved. Is there any sufficient and necessary conditions of $g$ that assures SOSD property?

Answer (score 1):

As long as $g(\cdot)$ is ***Nondecreasing*** and ***Concave***

Definition: For any lotteries $F$ and $G$, $F$ second-order stochastically dominates $G$ if and only if the decision maker weakly prefers $F$ to $G$ under every weakly *increasing concave* utility function $u$. [Link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf)